# how to view doc on connect function in socket module in python

Tags: python, sockets

**I want to view socket.connect function doc, I tried three ways. Only the last can see. If I want to view modle.functionName doc, how to do it?**

```
  python  python3
Python 3.3.2 (default, Sep  8 2013, 14:22:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> help(socket.connect)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
>>> help(connect)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'connect' is not defined
>>> help(socket)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a socket class in socket module and path will be `socket.socket.connect`:

```
import socket
help(socket.socket.connect)
```

Comment: that's mean help(class.modle.functionName) so help(socket.socket.conect).but the socket doc is saying :on module socket?how to know class or modle?

Comment: @fuyou001 if docs lack this information is just mean not good docs but everywhere in docs examples socket created with this call: s = socket.socket(...)